# JavaScript EventListener on new element added

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I want make an **EventListener** on new **querySelector** added.

```
var ele = document.querySelector("js-new-post-activity")
ele.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    console.log('New post added');
});
```

it is possible to do it with JavaScript or not? and thank you.

Comment: When you say "new element add" do you mean that the element may not exist at the time the JS is run? and may be added in future? If so, look into using event delegation.

Comment: Yes it's not exist, and added when there is new post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation will help you then

Comment: `document.querySelector("js-new-post-activity")` will target a `<js-new-post-activity>` element, I guess you wanted something like `document.querySelector(".js-new-post-activity")` which would target an element with the class `"js-new-post-activity"`